# How to improve perfomance of recyclerview from Api (list rending is very slow)?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi in the below task contains some list of items .I am calling an Api and rending the data and then setting the adapter and displaying in recyclerlistview.

But list is coming perfectly.For displaying it is taking too much of time .Becuase from Api all are strings and objects .No files or images

For displaying list it is taking time .I want to display very faster

Can any one help me where i did the mistake or give some suggestion

TaskFragment.java:

```
public class TaskFragement extends Fragment {

    private TaskAdapter taskAdapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewTask;
    Fragment fragment;
    String sessionId;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    String mobie;
    private ArrayList<TaskModel> listTask;
    Gson gson;
    private Object values;
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Task List");
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.account, container, false);

        FloatingActionButton fb= rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Create New Task");
                fragment = new TaskCreateFragement();
                sessionId = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("sessionId");
                loadFragment(fragment);
            }
        });
        recyclerViewTask = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerOpportunity);

        listTask = new ArrayList<>();
        taskAdapter = new TaskAdapter(requireContext(),listTask);
        recyclerViewTask.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        fetchJSON();
        return rootView;
    }


    private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        // load fragment
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private void fetchJSON(){

        sessionId = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("sessionId");
        String operation = "syncModuleRecords";
        String module = "Calendar";
        String syncToken="";
        String mode="public";
        final GetNoticeDataService service = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetNoticeDataService.class);

        /** Call the method with parameter in the interface to get the notice data*/
        Call<SyncModule> call = service.GetSyncModuleList(operation, sessionId, module,syncToken,mode);

        /**Log the URL called*/
        Log.i("URL Called", call.request().url() + "");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<SyncModule>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SyncModule> call, Response<SyncModule> response) {

                Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));

                    SyncModule syncModule = response.body();


                    String success = syncModule.getSuccess();

                    if (success.equals("true")) {
                        SyncResults results = syncModule.getResult();

                        Sync sync = results.getSync();

                        ArrayList<SyncUpdated> syncUpdateds = sync.getUpdated();

                        for (SyncUpdated syncUpdated : syncUpdateds) {

                            ArrayList<SyncBlocks> syncBlocks = syncUpdated.getBlocks();

                            String value = "";
                            String subject = "";
                            String taskType = "";
                            String assigned = "";
                            String scheduleDate = "";
                            String location = "";
                            String opportunityNo = "";
                            String status = "";
                            String outcome = "";

                            for (SyncBlocks syncBlocks1 : syncBlocks) {

                                String label = syncBlocks1.getLabel();
                                if (label.equals("Task Details")) {
                                    ArrayList<SynFields> synFields = syncBlocks1.getFields();

                                    for (SynFields synFields1 : synFields) {
                                        String name = synFields1.getName();
                                        values = synFields1.getValue();
                                        if (name.equals("subject")) {
                                            subject = String.valueOf(values);
                                        } else if (name.equals("cf_956")) {
                                            taskType = String.valueOf(values);
                                        } else if (name.equals("assigned_user_id")) {
                                            try {
                                                Gson gson = new Gson();
                                                String strJson = gson.toJson(values);
                                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strJson);
                                                String v = jsonObject.getString("label");
//
                                                assigned = v;
                                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                                Log.e("SalesStageFragment", "Exception is : " + ex.toString());
                                            }

                                        } else if (name.equals("potential")) {
                                            try {
                                                Gson gson = new Gson();
                                                String strJson = gson.toJson(values);
                                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strJson);
                                                String v = jsonObject.getString("label");
//                                            assigned_tos.add(v);
                                                opportunityNo = v;
                                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                                Log.e("SalesStageFragment", "Exception is : " + ex.toString());
                                            }

                                        } else if (name.equals("date_start")) {
                                            scheduleDate = String.valueOf(values);

                                        } else if (name.equals("taskstatus")) {
                                            status = String.valueOf(values);

                                        } else if (name.equals("location")) {
                                            location = String.valueOf(values);

                                        }
                                        else if (name.equals("cf_1015")) {
                                            outcome = String.valueOf(values);

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            TaskModel taskModel = new TaskModel(subject,taskType,assigned,scheduleDate,location,opportunityNo,status,outcome);
                            listTask.add(taskModel);
                            recyclerViewTask.setAdapter(taskAdapter);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }







            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SyncModule> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("error", t.getMessage());
            }


        });

    }

}
```

TaskAdapter.java:

```
public class TaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<TaskModel> tasklist;
    public TaskAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TaskModel> tasklist) {
        mContext=context;
        this.tasklist=tasklist;
    }

    @Override
    public TaskAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_task, parent, false);
        TaskAdapter.MyViewHolder holder = new TaskAdapter.MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TaskAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.subject.setText(tasklist.get(position).getSubject());
        holder.task_type.setText(tasklist.get(position).getTaskType());
        holder.assigned_to.setText(tasklist.get(position).getAssigned());
       // holder.related_to.setText(tasklist.get(position).);
        holder.outcome.setText(tasklist.get(position).getOutcome());
        holder.status.setText(tasklist.get(position).getStatus());
        holder.location.setText(tasklist.get(position).getLocation());
        holder.schedule_date.setText(tasklist.get(position).getScheduleDate());
        holder.schedule_date.setBackgroundResource(R.color.password);
        holder.opportunity.setText(tasklist.get(position).getOpportunityNo());

        final String status = tasklist.get(position).getStatus();
        if(status.equals("Scheduled")){
            holder.status.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
        } else if(status.equals("Completed")){
            holder.status.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.green));
        } else if(status.equals("In Complete")){
            holder.status.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return tasklist.size();
    }



    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView subject, outcome, status,task_type,assigned_to,related_to,schedule_date,location,opportunity,bill_pin;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            subject= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subject);
            outcome = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.outcome);
            status = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
            task_type = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_type);
            assigned_to = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.assigned_to);
            related_to = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.related_to);
            schedule_date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.schedule_date);
            location = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.location);
            opportunity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.opp_no);


        }


    }
}
```

Modelclass:

```
public class TaskModel {

    private String subject;
    private String taskType;
    private String assigned;
    private String scheduleDate;
    private String location;
    private String opportunityNo;

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getTaskType() {
        return taskType;
    }

    public void setTaskType(String taskType) {
        this.taskType = taskType;
    }

    public String getAssigned() {
        return assigned;
    }

    public void setAssigned(String assigned) {
        this.assigned = assigned;
    }

    public String getScheduleDate() {
        return scheduleDate;
    }

    public void setScheduleDate(String scheduleDate) {
        this.scheduleDate = scheduleDate;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getOpportunityNo() {
        return opportunityNo;
    }

    public void setOpportunityNo(String opportunityNo) {
        this.opportunityNo = opportunityNo;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getOutcome() {
        return outcome;
    }

    public void setOutcome(String outcome) {
        this.outcome = outcome;
    }

    private String status;

    public TaskModel(String subject, String taskType, String assigned, String scheduleDate, String location, String opportunityNo, String status, String outcome) {
        this.subject = subject;
        this.taskType = taskType;
        this.assigned = assigned;
        this.scheduleDate = scheduleDate;
        this.location = location;
        this.opportunityNo = opportunityNo;
        this.status = status;
        this.outcome = outcome;
    }

    private String outcome;





}
```

Comment: Instead of load all data symontenously do pagination will help you to display data faster. https://github.com/Suleiman19/Android-Pagination-with-RecyclerView